# Jolt: Retrieve element from array based on mapping key

Tags: json, jolt

I'm new to jolt and I'm facing issues with the following transformation. I need to retrieve an element from a list based on two keys matching: mapId = mappings.*.mapId. The element to retrieve is the steps array.

Input:

```
  {
    "name": "New LMO",
    "mapId": "3100",
    "mappings": [
      {
        "mapId": "9002",
        "steps": [
          {
            "label": "0AA2",
            "order": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mapId": "3100",
        "steps": [
          {
            "label": "0CA4",
            "order": 1
          },
          {
            "label": "0CA5",
            "order": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
  {
    "name": "New LMO",
    "mapId": "3100",
    "steps": [
      {
        "label": "0CA4",
        "order": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "0CA5",
        "order": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it possible to do this transformation using Jolt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on similar post answered by @barbaros Özhan:
[Jolt Transform - Filter Array Where Fields equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741598/jolt-transform-filter-array-where-fields-equal)

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "mapId": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&1"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "*": {
          "mapId": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,)": "&1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "1": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```