# How to check if an item exists in an array?

Tags: json, jolt

Here is a sample input JSON with an array and an item to find:

**Input** :

```json
{
  "numbers": [
    "1234",
    "9999",
    "0123",
    "2311",
    "9911",
    "5410"
  ],
  "number": "9999"
}
```

**Output** :

```json
{
  "numberExists": "true"
}
```

Both the fields are dynamic and I cannot hard-code anything.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on similar post answered by @barbaros Özhan: [Jolt Transform - Filter Array Where Fields equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741598/jolt-transform-filter-array-where-fields-equal)

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "number": {
        "$": "@(1)"
      },
      "numbers": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "number": {
            "#true": "numberExists"
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
   ,
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "numberExists": "false"
    }
  }


]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following transformation as an alternative to my previous solution which is presented within the other answer :

```json
[
  { // match the attribute of the object and components of the array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "numbe*": {
        "$": "@0",    // pick up from the attribute of the object
        "*": {
          "$": "@0[]" // pick up from the components of the array
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // determine whether exists a match
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=size"
    }
  },
  { // check out for the size value of 2 to show up the existence
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "2": {
          "#true": "numberExists"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Another smart, even shorter solution might be

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "numbe*": {
        "$": "@0",
        "*": {
          "#true": "@0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": {
          "@": "numberExists"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Btw, if returning the else case matters(unlike the the current question's text), then you might add

```json
  ,
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "numberExists": "false"
    }
  }
```

to the end of these transformations as presented in the other answer as well.